# In Objective C, is it possible to "connect" a variable to another one?

Tags: objective-c, variables, int

I have an "int i = 0;", and also, "int b;"
I want the variable "b" to be set to whatever value "i" is for the durainder of the appliaction.
So in the beginning, "b" would be set to "i", so "b" would be 0.
But if "i" suddenly change in the app, I'd like "b" to automatically set to what "i" is.

Note: I gave the integers as an example, I'm actually asking these questions for NSStrings
If you do not understand the question, please comment!

Comment: why not just use i for everything and never have a variable b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int`s are a C integral type — they're not anything specific to Objective-C. So you'd achieve what you want by making b a pointer to i. E.g.

```
int i = 0;
int *b;
b = &i;

NSLog(@"value is currently %d", *b);

i = 2;

NSLog(@"value is now %d", *b);
```

What that means in C is that `i` is an integer and `b` is a container for the address of an integer. `&i` evaluates to the address of `i` so `b = &i;` means 'put the address of i into b'. `*b` means 'the value of the thing at the address contained in b' (contrast with just `b` which would be 'the address stored in b').

It will become invalid to access `*b` when `i` no longer exists.

Comment: What about with NSStrings? I was actually just using the integers as examples.

Comment: It's the same for NSStrings except `i` has type `NSString *` and `b` has type `NSString **`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is allot similar to a global variable. In that case whenever you change the value of I you also change the value of B. But maybe you can solve your problem with notifications (events) but it i'm not sure.

Comment: Actually the answer from Tommy is the best approach if you don't want to use global variables.